# browser based game registration

Tags: coordinates

Fore example, user register to the game, and he gets coordinates (5;5).
Another user gets coordinates somewhere near user before, lets say (8;5), and so on. So all latest registered users are close to each other.

The question is - What is the best way to generate coordinate close to user before?

Sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1):

First, you must defined how far a new user will appear and then, generate a position from an existing user.

As an example, let say there's a user in (2;6) and a new user register. You defined that the max distance the newly registered user will appear is 5 units. The position of the newly registered users will be something like :
x = 2 +/- random (0-5) 
y = 6 +/- random (0-5)

This way, the new use may appear in (5;4), (7;2), (3;5).....

Answer (score 1):

You should decide on what the distance of new user depends.

Case 1: All users spawn near some point, say (50;50) with max deviation of 25 on both axes.

Case 2: All users spawn near previous spawn point with some deviation.

Case 3: All users spawn near previous spawn point with deviation based on time of registration difference, for example if two users registered at the same moment, they will spawn at the same point, but if the second user spawned 2 minutes after the first, the deviation will be multiplied by 2.

---

Either way, you will have to save the last spawn point in order to calculate a new one from it.

As for what's best — you'll have to choose yourself.